# Where is the data used in secure boot process stored?

Tags: secure-boot

I am spent a lot of time researching and reading about this topic but I am now very confused.

I have read that computer manufacturers include some Microsoft keys.  For example, Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA, seems to be a key that somehow lets a system boot to Linux distros that are signed by Microsoft.  I'd like to understand where these are stored.  For example, is it on your hard drive?  Where is other data in the secure boot process read from?  What are the steps that secure boot goes through?

Sorry if I am using some terminology incorrectly.  I am doing my best.

Comment: Its not on your hard drive. Microsoft product keys can be stored in the UEFI firmware "BIOS" on OEM computers.   The boot process is something quite different, and relates to chains of trust.  This relates to Secureboot and TPM - TPM being firmware which can allow limited access to unique and system information using tpm chips.   Googling "TPM Trousers" may be useful as it talks about Linux TPM which gives you the idea of the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Your motherboard has a small amount of built-in storage, where it primarily keeps the "BIOS settings" (like the boot order) – in the past this was known as "CMOS memory", now it's more commonly called "NVRAM" and is of somewhat higher capacity.

Physically, it's just some sort of "flash" memory or maybe EEPROM (I don't know which) that the firmware can read/write, but the OS can't – not directly, at least.

In UEFI type firmware, the data that's stored in the NVRAM is structured in terms of "EFI variables" and the firmware *does* allow the OS to access them – but still, only through the functions provided by firmware, not directly at block level. (It's a lot like how the OS allows your regular apps to use the HDD/SSD but only through file management functions – it does permission checks, etc.)

The list of operating systems in UEFI is stored as "EFI variables" in the motherboard's NVRAM – when the OS is installed, it calls the firmware function to create a variable named `Boot0002` or similar, with specified data.

Secure Boot settings are mostly the same. There is a variable named `db` that lists the certificates allowed to sign operating systems (the MS UEFI CA certificate is stored in db), and the only thing special about it is that the firmware requires the new value itself to be digitally signed.

At boot time, the initial OS files are validated against certificates listed in 'db'; updates to 'db' must be signed with the certificate found in 'KEK', and updates to that are verified against 'PK'. (The firmware settings screen can bypass those checks and let *you* import any certificate – but the OS can't.)

If you are running Linux, take a look at `/sys/firmware/efi` and you'll find the list of EFI variables currently stored in the NVRAM, including the ones used by Secure Boot. You also have tools like `efi-readvar` to dump a formatted list of the Secure Boot certificates, or `efibootmgr -v` to list the boot options – they both get their data from EFI through the Linux-provided /sys interface. (There are similar tools for PowerShell in Windows.)

---

Note regarding the TPM – while some manufacturers *might* put some SB-related parameters in the TPM's own NVRAM, that is not required; it's just one possible way the manufacturer can comply with the tamper resistance requirement, but most Secure Boot implementations do not use the TPM in this way at all. (Indeed many don't even have a TPM.)

Secure Boot only involves the TPM in that the current satate is appended into its *event log* and hashed into the "PCR" registers – which are all kept in volatile RAM and their purpose is measuring each individual boot, not persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI Secure Boot is a feature defined in the UEFI Specification. It guarantees that only valid 3rd party firmware code can run in the Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) firmware environment. UEFI Secure Boot assumes the system firmware is a trusted entity. Any 3rd party firmware code is not trusted, including the bootloader installed by the Operating System Vendor (OSV) and peripherals provided by an Independent Hardware Vendor (IHV).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).